# Whose part of the system should handle malformed messages?

Tags: web-services, server, client

Currently we have a POS (point of sale) application that should call a remote service to declare each new sale. Considering that the remote service could be not reachable we have also a local db at the POS . 
 Actually , there are multiple reason for which a sale culd not be declared on the remote service :

1. We are not handling any version policy for our remote service
   and from time to time the POS and the remote service could be not
   aligned on the same interface.  so lets called this a kind of
   problem a malformed request to the remote service.
2. The remote
   service is not available or reachable : let's called this a network
   issue
3. The remote sale service is doing some business and
   invariant checks and could raise a n eventual business exception.
   The problem is that the sale have already be made, so the sale
   service should in theory only register the sale operation...

For the developpers working on the POS application, they have a lot to handle : first making the sale, and registring in local DB the operation, then call the remote service and deal with various exception in case of which they have to regsiter their request in the local db for debuging/correctig purpose.So they think that the remote server should accept of type of sale declaration and deal with the eventual malformed request.
 As you guess, for the team working on the remote sale service : they disagree. They think that all the clients of their service should use the same version of interface as they use, and deal with malformed message or business exception on their side. They want their job to be easy as taking the payload and register it in their db.

So my question : if a sale registration failed on the server, does the POS team have to register the failed operation and then debug manually to fix the record and submit again at the sales registration server ? Or do you think it'a a job of the registration server ? 
I think that the pos application should only handle the case :
 1 and 2. Thank you for any advices.

Answer (score 1):

This human behavior is known as pushing the work around. We all want our job to be the easy job.

The acid question to resolve it is this: Is there some business critical feature that the remote system doesn't allow you to provide with their existing interface?

Clients rarely get to dictate protocols to servers. The above is about the only leverage you have to force a change. If you can make it work using their interface you should. If you can't you need to specify exactly what you need. And even after you do, don't expect that will make them conform to your format. They will want an interface that keeps all their clients working as is while adding your one little optional feature that no one else uses.

What you need are clear examples of properly formed messages, preferably with example code. If they're making you reverse engineer the protocol from exceptions only, they have failed to document their interface. That's simply unprofessional. But before you call them on that be sure you haven't overlooked the documentation.

This isn't a small part of the job. Adapting your records to theirs, and back, is something you should have in your plan.